# MongoDB native: is there any difference between toString and toHexString methods?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, node-mongodb-native, objectid

I'm using Node.js v0.12.0 with MongoDB driver v1.4.34. So, is there any difference between converting ObjectID to String with toString and toHexString methods?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`toHexString` method returns the ObjectID id as a 24 byte hex string representation.

```
// Create a new ObjectID
var objectId = new ObjectID();
// Verify that the hex string is 24 characters long
assert.equal(24, objectId.toHexString().length);
```

You won't need to base64 encode the result of calling `toString` on an `ObjectId` as it's returned as a hex number already. You could also call: `_id.toHexString()` to get the hex value directly.
 Click this link to see MongoDB source ([toString just wraps toHexString](https://github.com/mongodb/js-bson/blob/b0d62c3b32d7dc8a76d6ce60e272c916b8a301a1/lib/bson/objectid.js#L123-L131)).

Comment: The last line in this answer is the most important here. The short answer is: No, there is no difference.